# Requests HTTP headers

Tags: python, http, http-headers, python-requests, response

I've a trouble with the HTTP headers that the module Requests returns.

I'm using the following code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests 

response = requests.get("http://www.google.co.il",proxies={'http': '','https':''})

data = response.text 
# response.text returns the appropriate html code 
# (<!doctype html><html dir="rtl" itemscope=""....)

if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    # How do I send those headers to the conn (browser)   
    print "HEADERS: " + str(response.headers) 
    conn.send(data)
```

I'm trying to send a GET request to www.google.co.il, and send the response to the browser (on the example I called it "conn"). The problem is that the browser won't show the received HTML code and instead I'm receiving ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.
The headers in the response are :

```
HEADERS: {'Content-Length': '5451', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Set-Cookie': 'NID=103=RJzu4RTCNxkh-75dvKBHx-_jen9M8iPes_AdOIQqzBVZ0VPTz1PlQaAVLpwYOmxZlTKmcogiDb1VoY__Es0HqSNwlkmHl3SuBZC8_8XUfqh1PzdWTjrXRnB4S738M1lm; expires=Wed, 08-Nov-2017 10:05:46 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.co.il; HttpOnly', 'Expires': '-1', 'Server': 'gws', 'Cache-Control': 'private, max-age=0', 'Date': 'Tue, 09 May 2017 10:05:46 GMT', 'P3P': 'CP="This is not a P3P policy! See https://www.google.com/support/accounts/answer/151657?hl=en for more info."', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=windows-1255', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN'}
```

Someone told me that the problem is that I'm not sending any header to the browser. Is this really the problem ? Any other suggestions ? and if it is the problem, how do I send the appropriate headers to the browser ?

Edit: I forgot to mention that the connection is 
through a Proxy server.

Any help would be great!

Thanks alot, Yahli.

Comment: What is the `conn` ? Socket ?

Comment: Yes, `conn`  is a socket.

Comment: Someting like an intercepting proxy right ?  You have to send a complete HTTP response to the browser , not just the body . If you're using sockets , you can skip `requests` and send the HTTP request with `socket` . If you insist on using `requests` , you 'll have to construct the header from the `response` object .

Comment: @t.m.adam Mind to write an answer with those methods ? because I have no clue how to either send http request with `socket` or build the header from the response.

Comment: Ok , give me a second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find anything about geting the raw http response ( not `response.raw` ) in `requests` documentation so i wrote a function :

```
def http_response(response):
    return 'HTTP/1.1 {} {}\r\n{}\r\n\r\n{}'.format(
        response.status_code, response.reason , 
        '\r\n'.join(k + ': ' + v for k, v in response.headers.items()), 
        response.content
    )
```

I tested it by setting Firefox HTTP proxy to localhost:port ( with a listening socket on port ) , and it works fine .

Alternatively you can get the host from `conn.recv` , open a new socket to that host, and send the data .  Example :

```
data = conn.recv(1024)
host = [ l.split(':')[1].strip() for l in data.splitlines() if l.startswith('Host:') ]
if len(host)  : 
    cli = socket.socket()
    cli.connect((host[0], 80))
    cli.send(data)
    response = ''
    while True : 
        data = cli.recv(1024)
        if not data.strip() : 
            break
        response += data
    conn.send(response)
    cli.close()
```

Where `conn` is the connection to the web browser . This is just a quick example , assuming you have only HTTP requests ( port 80 ) . There is room for much optimization

Comment: Unfortunately when I'm trying to connect to 'www.google.com' I'm receiving this error in the browser:  ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED (same with any other HTTP/s) and it doesn't show the correct website. I do receive the correct html dump tho. Any ideas why this is happening ? (I'll upvote you only in 5hrs, I've exceeded my max vote number lol)

Comment: I can't be sure unless i see your code , but if you're building an intecepting proxy , it's an ssl issue . google uses HTTPS only , you should sslwrap your socket ( create a cert, add it to trusted authorities , etc ). Try connecting to stackoverflow on port 80 and let me know what happens

Comment: That's my complete code : [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/TtmaDLAs). If you would help me solve this specific problem I would be greatful! The code is taken from the class Server in the function _https. Regarding to what you said, I thought that the module Requests handles those already, should I create a requests session then ?

Comment: Nice work so far , but there is much more to be done if you want to handle HTTPS . This has nothing to do with `requests` , it's about the server , and it's more than a fiew lines of code .

Comment: Do you have any instructions ? what should I read or docs I can use ? :)

Comment: Basically , your browser will send a CONNECT request to your proxy .  You have to respond 200 , and sslwrap the socket . You also need to create a certificate and key ( use openssl ) , and add that cert to your browser's trusted authorities . I can't give you a link at the moment , but you should find many examples on github

Comment: If you don't care about intercepting HTTPS traffic or using `requests`, you can skip the sslwrap and the certificate parts, and use `select.select` with a small timeout in a loop ( like in the `admin_connection` function of your script ) . If you choose this method you should set a flag to break the loop , eg if nothing is recieved after 4 iterations . Still, it will be much easier this way . If you're doing this for fun or research, i recommend trying both methods

Comment: I've successfully made it using select as you said. I also used [this](https://github.com/inaz2/proxy2) as a document. Thanks for your help and guidance!